# React16 error just popped up and I don't know why

Tags: reactjs

G'day.  I had some code of mine working for yonks.  I shifted the directory it lives in and nothing else and I get a weird error on the render() return.

```
ERROR in /disk/dev/www/smartForm/smartForm.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (244:16)

  242 |         }
  243 |         
> 244 |         return( <div>
      |                 ^
  245 |                     {formOut}
  246 |                 </div>
  247 |         );
```

Here is the code.  I haven't touched this bit much (as I remember) for a while.

```
  //--------
    render() {

        let formIn  = this.props.form;                                  // JSON description of FORM
        let formOut = null;                                             // contructed REACT/Javascript form


        switch (formIn.format) {                                        // what type of operation is this
            case 'accordion': {                                         // Accordion in a FORM, OK
                let children = this.pages(formIn.pages,
                                          formIn.format);               // build the children
                formOut = React.createElement(Accordion,                // construct the parent with ALL nested CHILDREN after
                                            {key: formIn.formName},     // just a unique key 
                                            children);                  // N ACCORDION pages, N2 input fields
                break;
            }
            case 'workflow': {
                let children = this.pages(formIn.pages,                 // build the children
                                          formIn.format);               // build the children
                formOut = React.createElement(Workflow,                 // and create the complex sheet element
                                            { key: formIn.formName},
                                            children);                  // N SLIDING pages, N2 input fields
                break;
            }
            case 'simple': {
                let children = this.pages(formIn.pages,                 // build the children
                                          formIn.format);               // build the children
                formOut = React.createElement(Simple,
                                            { key: formIn.formName},
                                            children);                  // One page, N input fields
                break;
            }
        }

        return( <div>
                    {formOut}
                </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SmartForm;

//-----------------   EOF -------------------------------------------------
```

Got me stumped.  Cheers!

Comment: Your webpack / Babel configuration is probably different in the new directory, the problem here is that your JSX isn't being transpiled.

Comment: Look for the error in your build tools, not code. The file is just not recognized as a JSX file and considered to be plain JS, where tags are invalid.

Comment: Thanks.  I shifted the thing a few flights upstairs out of the application directory so it sits like

NewApplication
   app
      server
      client
         src
            containers
                my_form_stuff.js

smartForm

Comment: {
      test: /\.js?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: 'react-hot-loader/webpack!babel-loader'
    }]

Is it the test that needs to be changed?